# getting a value from a field in firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve a specific value of a field and store it inside a variable named joiningScore. This makes joiningScore a object with a promise that has a value in it. How can I get that value. I tried tucking in a .then method after the .get("currentPos") but it throws an error saying docSnapshot.get().then is not a function.

`var joiningScore = positionDoc.get().then((docSnapshot) => { return docSnapshot.get("currentPos");      })`

```
  const positionDoc = frebase.firestore().collection('position').doc('kY3k3lmnCIVG3Qi6LxUZ');
```

here positionDoc is a reference to the document in firestore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are assigning to a variable a [Promise chain](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining).

You need to wait that the Promise returned by the `get()` method is fulfilled in order to get the value. See this [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) for more details.

So something along these line should work:

```
const positionDoc = firebase.firestore().collection('position').doc('kY3k3lmnCIVG3Qi6LxUZ');

var joiningScore;

positionDoc.get().then((docSnapshot) => {
   joiningScore = docSnapshot.get("currentPos");      
})
```

---

You could also use an async function as follows:

```
async function getJoiningScore() {
    const positionDoc = firebase.firestore().collection('position').doc('kY3k3lmnCIVG3Qi6LxUZ');
    
    const docSnapshot = await positionDoc.get();
    return docSnapshot.get("currentPos");      
    
}
```

Note that this function is itself asynchronous.

Comment: The first method makes joiningScore undefined and the second method returns a similar promise as before

Comment: Are you sure the doc and the field exist? Also note that it is only within the callback passed to `then()` that you get a value for `joiningScore`. For the second method, you need to either use then() or async/await, since it is asynchronous. I would kindly suggest you read the three following articles about asynchronous JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing and https://medium.com/codebuddies/getting-to-know-asynchronous-javascript-callbacks-promises-and-async-await-17e0673281ee and https://alligator.io/js/async-functions/